# What video chat works between the Android and iOS?

Tags: ios, compatibility, video-calling

What video chat works between the Android and iOS? For example between a Samsung Galaxy and iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Skype and Hangouts should work. There are probably other apps too, but you can google them yourself

Comment: Is Hangout available on iOS?

Comment: Yes. https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/hangouts/id643496868?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

You should try Skype, The best way to achieve Video Calls over the phone , Free and Easy to use